# HTML5 form validation without submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

i want to validate the form inputs without an type="submit" button. 
How can i do this?

I tried this ->

```
<script type="text/javascript">function validateForm() {
    $('#form1')[0].checkValidity()
   if( document.form1.vorname.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.nachname.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.postleitzahl.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.email.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.telefon_optin_Ja.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
    }
if( document.form1.ort.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.straße.value == "" )
   {
         return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.Anrede.value == "" )
   {
         return false;


        }else { 
            $('#modal_absenden').modal({
              backdrop: 'static',
              keyboard: 'false',
                 })

    }
}
</script>
```

My form name is: form1 , button -> `Absenden

The "background" of the question is: I want to validate the form inputs first, then (if all inputs ok) it should opens a modal, where u can select the redirect page (redirect yes, redirect no) then it submit the form via post to mail.php.

I hope u understand my question, if u have questions, pls ask. (My english is not so good..)

Thank you for help.

Comment: Use `on( "keyup", handler )`. http://api.jquery.com/keyup/.

Comment: Take a look at livevalidation.com or this: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/XqPhQ/

Answer (score 1):

You have said about HTML5.

Then that means all you have to do is to use checkValidity() along with

```
 <input type="text" name="name" required>
<input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
```

Here is the nice article about using HTML5 validation.

I have not used by myself. But I am glad to know a bit from your post.

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

If you want to use jQuery one then go for validation.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213138/An-Example-to-Use-jQuery-Validation-Plugin

Comment: Yes , thats right. I am using the required tag. But it will only validate if u are using a submit button. When i´m using the submit button on the frontend(not the modal), it will validate, but not open the modal to choose the redirect.. I hope u are understanding what i mean

Comment: for model what are you using as jquery dialog ? I would like to see by myself if there is an issue.

Comment: please take a look at http://www.doggy-dinner.de/.. for open the modal i have the js snippet (look at my first poast)... if i hit the "enter" button on my keyboard the validation popup appears, but not on click on the type="button"

Comment: umm ok why don't you just use type submit and cancel the form submit. This way you are still calling validation? here is the code. $('#membershipform').submit(function(event){
    if ($(this).checkValidity || $(this).checkValidity()) {
    }else
 {
event.preventDefault();
}
});

I have not checked the code but it should do the job.

Comment: When i am using submit button it will skip the modal, because it calls the action attribute, i.e mail.php. Ill check the code edit: it skips the modal when using type="submit" , if i am using type="button" the validation will not perform edit2: if u want to check this , open the site again and test it with test inputs ;)

Comment: it seem to be that the html5 validation cant called without an submit button :(

Comment: I am way from desk I hope I will try tomorrow and see if I can find

Answer (score 0):

You could call your validate function everytime an input changes:

```
$('#form1 input').change(validateForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you want to do frontend validation with Javascript. There are wrapped library to do this. E.g., [validate.js](http://validatejs.org/), [verifyjs](http://verifyjs.com/), and [this one](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/), ...

And you can bind the validation process on the blur event of an input
[JQuery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) is a good choice with clear documentation. You just need to download the .js library and place it somewhere under your web folder, and using  tag to include it. And call the .validate() function on the form you want to validate. That should be done.

```
$('input').on('blur', function(){
    $("#myForm").validate();
});
```

Comment: Sorry i wanted to use the bootstrap validation, is this html5 or js?! Im not so familiar with Js..

Comment: It's JS, but you may not need to deal with JS code. To validate, you need to download bootstrap Javascript codes. And set the attribute <input class="input ..." required> which means this field cannot be empty.

Comment: But there is the problem i tried to explain. The submit button is starting the validation. But i cant use the submit button on the form , because i have to open the modal. If i am using a submit button for this, it´ll skip the modal because it opens the actions=mail.php.. Hope you understand my problem :x

Comment: So you have to do with JS. I suggest JQuery validation. See the edited answer. And make sure you have used JQuery (the mostly wide-used JS library).

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
$("#form1 input").on('change,blur', validateForm); 

function validateForm() {
    // Caution : this refers to the HTMLElement
}
```

You shoud consider to use a jQuery form validation like library like http://formvalidator.net/ or http://jqueryvalidation.org/ or create yours.

Cheers